# SharePoint search query: display people from a specific AD group

Tags: caml-query, active-directory, query, people-search

I want to display all members / users who are in the Active Directory group "Marketing".
What do I have to add / change to the following query so that I don't see all users, but only those from the AAD group "Marketing"?

```
ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

In addition, I have mapped a managed property "RefinableString111" to the craweld property "People: SPS-MemberOf"

Comment: Check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e338a74a-c5ff-4933-9f3b-b775206ebd1b/syntax-for-people-search-that-belong-to-a-particular-ad-group) if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If the property mapping worked and if the values populated, you will probably want a "contains" query. The syntax is `refinablestring111:Marketing`. This depends on what the values in the property are and how they are organized. The contains query is your best friend.

You may want to look at the Search Query Tool